# Mongoose - Reference a field from another table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two tables: `Post` and `User` and I want to reference the User name in the Post table.

I can reference the ID but I also need the name.

User model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Post model:

```
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema)
```

In the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) they said:

> Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs.
> However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and
> have a good reason for doing so.

However I couldn't find an example on how I can do this.

Comment: You can only set `_id` as a reference and get a name of the user using `populate()` when finding it.